# capture warnings with capture.output

Tags: r, sink

I am having problems using `capture.output()` and I can't figure out why, since it is for the most part just a wrapper for `sink()`.

Consider this trivial example using `sink()`:

```r
foo = function() warning("foo")

f = file()
sink(f, type = "message")
foo()
readLines(f)
## [1] "Warning message:" "In foo() : foo"  
close(f)
```

This works as expected. however, `capture.output()` does not :

```r
f = file()
capture.output(foo(), file = f, type = "message")
## Warning message:
## In foo() : foo
readLines(f)
## character(0)
close(f)
```

`capture.output()` *does* work for messages though:

```r
bar = function() message("bar")
f = file()
capture.output(bar(), file = f, type = "message")
readLines(f)
## [1] "bar"
close(f)
```

But according to the documentation both messages and warnings should be captured:

> Messages sent to `stderr()` (including those from `message`, `warning` and `stop`) are captured by `type = "message"`.

**What am I missing here?**

Comment: See https://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Capturing-warnings-with-capture-output-td912468.html and https://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Capturing-all-warnings-with-messages-td922303.html. The problem is that warnings aren't printed till the top level function returns. With `sink()` that's not problem because you call `foo()` in it's own afterward. But with `capture.output()` the `foo()` function is called inside the wrapper so warnings aren't printed until `capture.output()` returns and at that point it's closed the redirection.

Comment: Thank you @MrFlick! This explains the issue, and also points to a possible solution: using the argument `immediate = TRUE` to force the warning to print immediately rather than waiting for the top-level function to return.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@MrFlick's comment points to a potential solution, provide you have control over the arguments that are passed to `warning()`. If you use the argument `immediate. = TRUE` then `capture.output()` can retrieve the warning message.

```r
baz = function() warning("baz", immediate. = TRUE)
res = capture.output(baz(), type = "message")
print(res)
## [1] "Warning in baz() : baz"
```

**EDIT**

Alternatively, @user2554330 points out you can use `options(warn = 1)` to globally make warnings print immediately.

```
oldopt = getOption("warn")
options(warn = 1)
res = capture.output(foo(), type = "message")
print(res)
## [1] "Warning in foo() : foo"
options(warn = oldopt)
```

**EDIT 2**

For completeness, I think it's helpful to point out this alternative approach using `withCallingHandlers`, which does not require any changes to options and may be a cleaner solution depending on the application. Consider this example of nested warnings:

```r
foo = function() {
  warning("foo")
  bar()
}
bar = function() { 
  warning("bar")
  baz()
}
baz = function() {
  warning("baz")
  TRUE
}
# create a container to hold warning messages
logs = vector("character")
# function to capture warning messages
log_fun = function(w) logs <<- append(logs, w$message)
# function call with message capturing
withCallingHandlers(foo(), warning = log_fun)
## [1] TRUE
## Warning messages:
## 1: In foo() : foo
## 2: In bar() : bar
## 3: In baz() : baz
print(logs)
## [1] "foo" "bar" "baz"
```

Note that `withCallingHandlers` allows you to specify different behavior for different signal conditions, e.g. `warnings` and `messages` could be stored in separate variables.

Comment: You can set `options(warn = 1)` to make warnings print immediately.